# Web Service Method with Optional Parameters

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, optional-parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I have an optional parameter for an ASP.NET SOAP web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723052/can-i-have-an-optional-parameter-for-an-asp-net-soap-web-service)

I have tried looking around for this but I really cannot find the right solution for what I want to do. Sorry for the repetition since I know this has been asked before. I have a Web Service Method in which I want to have an optional parameter such as:

```
public void MyMethod(int a, int b, int c = -3)
```

I already know I cannot use nullable parameters, so I am just trying to use a default value. Problem is when I call this method without supplying argument c is still get an exception. Is there somewhere I have to specify it is in fact optional?

Thanksю

Comment: ASP.NET Web Service (asmx) or WCF?

Comment: @steve Kiss have you found any soln?

Comment: This is not a duplicate i guess.. especially because of the answer. The old question(2009) metions workaround without overload (possible older version of ASP.NET).. and current thread(2011) answer shows real overloads are possible.

Comment: Right solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/47784210/2936295

Answer (score 31):

You can achieve optional parameters by overloads and using the MessageName property.

```
[WebMethod(MessageName = "MyMethodDefault")]
public void MyMethod(int a, int b)
{
      MyMethod( a, b, -3);
}

[WebMethod(MessageName = "MyMethod")]
public void MyMethod(int a, int b, int c)
```

For this to work, you may also need to change

```
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
```

to

```
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.None)]
```

if you haven't done so already, as `WS-I Basic Profile v1.1` does not allow overloads

Comment: To make this work, you may also need to change [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)] to [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.None)] as WS-I Basic Profile v1.1 does not allow overloads

Comment: I have a perfect solution here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71273352/3715484

Answer (score 10):

Use methods overloading:

```
[WebMethod(MessageName = "MyMethod1")]
public void MyMethod(int a, int b)
{
    return MyMethod(a, b, -3);
}

[WebMethod(MessageName = "MyMethod2")]
public void MyMethod(int a, int b, int c)
{
}
```

Comment: How would I call it from the service?

Comment: @Si8 do you mean how to call this service now? The easiest way would be to generate a proxy class using Visual Studio

Comment: I was able to figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: I have the perfect solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71273352/3715484

Answer (score 3):

I've looked into optional parameters etc. before, and straight asmx web services don't support this (with default generated WSDLs). With WCF however, you can mark parameters in your datacontract as IsRequired=false - see [Optional parameters in ASP.NET web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995521/asp-net-web-service-optional-parameters)