# 3rp party is posting JSON with an optional (string) parameter to my vb/asp.net api, how do I handle this?

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net

I do not have any control over the data being posted. They are posting to an address that I specify, and appending "/api_method" to the end, so the address looks like "myserver.com/myapi/default.aspx/api_method."

They are posting something similar to:

```
{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"}
```

and Key3 may or may not be passed, which is the entirety of my issue...

I'm receiving the data on default.aspx.vb in a web method:

```
 <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function api_method(ByVal key1 As String, ByVal key2As String, ByVal key3 As String) As api_method_response
```

and obviously, if Key3 is missing, I throw an error...

I have tried changing key3 from string, to an "object" of "Key3"

```
Public Class Key3
    Property Key_3 As String = "test"
End Class
```

and this didn't seem to work either (maybe I am doing that wrong).

I thought `as nullable(of string)` was the ticket but soon learned string "is already nullable" so that didn't work either...

Any suggestions? Am I going about things all wrong?

Thanks!

Edit:
Thanks to Pablo Romeo, overloading is the answer:

I changed my default.aspx.vb to have:

```
    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
        Public Shared Function api_method(ByVal key1 As String, ByVal key2As String, ByVal key3 As String) As api_method_response
'stuff here
end function

<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
        Public Shared Function api_method(ByVal key1 As String, ByVal key2As String) As api_method_response
'stuff here (note: no key 3)
end function
```

and everything appears to work!

Comment: Would method overloading work in your case? As shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7565972/1373170
Just define two methods, one with and one without Key3, and from the one without, call the other one with Key3's default value, and you should be set.

Comment: Well that was easy... thanks!!!

Comment: No prob, I'll just post it as an answer, in case somebody else finds it useful.

Comment: Cool, I marked (and upvoted) as well as edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would method overloading work in your case? 
You can see an example here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7565972/1373170

Just define two methods, one with and one without Key3, and from the one without, call the other one with Key3's default value, and you should be set.